# Unique task manager per virtual desktop on KDE 4.5

Tags: kde, virtual-desktop

I created two virtual desktops in KDE 4.5 and I would like to have a separate task manager (widget in the panel that displays the current opened programs) per virtual desktop.

I could not find a way to do this. I also tried to create an activity, but again, the task manager was the same for both activities.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh well,

I [asked on the KDE forum](http://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?t=90721) and it seems that panels are global so it's not possible to have unique panels per virtual deskop.

Comment: This is ashame.

Comment: I don't understand this at all - what is the point of a virtual desktop then??

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this is new to KDE 4.7, but now right clicking on the task manager and choosing settings provides a checkbox that says "Only show tasks from current desktop".  That works for me.